# 2D bin packing problem with rectpack python

Tags: python

I have datas containing ID, length, width, and quantity for items I need to pack into bins/containers (1 bin size), I tried using rectpack library and it did plot all bin placement perfectly as I thought, but when I check the graphs it seems like some item have mismatched dimension, and also some items are placed more than required (more than the quantity stated on the data before)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rectpack import newPacker

# Load data from the Excel file
file_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Transport/module dimensions.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Detect column names
item_identity_column = df.columns[0]
width_column = df.columns[1]
height_column = df.columns[2]
amount_column = df.columns[3]

# Extract width, height, and amount from the DataFrame
rectangles = [(row[width_column], row[height_column], row[amount_column]) for _, row in df.iterrows()]

# Initialize the packer
packer = newPacker()

# Set bin size
bin_width, bin_height = 81, 22

# Pack the rectangles into the bins
current_bin = 0
while rectangles:
    # Add a new bin (container)
    packer.add_bin(bin_width, bin_height)

    # Add rectangles to the packer
    for i, (width, height, amount) in enumerate(rectangles):
        for _ in range(amount):
            packer.add_rect(width, height, rid=i)

    # Pack the rectangles into the current bin
    packer.pack()

    # Retrieve the packed rectangles for the current bin
    packed_rectangles = packer[current_bin]

    # Remove packed rectangles from the list
    rectangles = [rect for i, rect in enumerate(rectangles) if i not in set(r.rid for r in packed_rectangles)]

    # Plot the rectangles and label their centers for the current bin
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for rect in packed_rectangles:
        x, y, w, h = rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x, y), w, h, linewidth=1, edgecolor='b', facecolor='none'))
        ax.text(x + w / 2, y + h / 2, f"#{rect.rid + 1}", ha='center', va='center', color='r')

        # Add lines for distance (1 unit) between centers
        for other_rect in packed_rectangles:
            if rect != other_rect:
                other_x, other_y = other_rect.x + other_rect.width / 2, other_rect.y + other_rect.height / 2
                distance = ((x + w / 2 - other_x) ** 2 + (y + h / 2 - other_y) ** 2) ** 0.5
                if distance <= 1:
                    ax.plot([x + w / 2, other_x], [y + h / 2, other_y], color='gray', linestyle='--')

    # Add axis lines with a scale of 5 units
    ax.set_xticks(range(0, bin_width + 1, 5))
    ax.set_yticks(range(0, bin_height + 1, 5))
    ax.grid(True, linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)

    # Set axis limits
    ax.set_xlim(0, bin_width)
    ax.set_ylim(0, bin_height)

    # Set aspect ratio to be equal
    ax.set_aspect('equal')

    # Set axis labels
    ax.set_xlabel('Length')
    ax.set_ylabel('Width')

    # Set graph title
    ax.set_title(f'Placement #{current_bin + 1}')

    # Show the plot
    plt.show()

    # Move to the next bin
    current_bin += 1
```

data I used on my drive folder:

```
ID  a   b   amount
1   15  18  1
2   12  28  6
3   5   14  3
4   12  15  1
5   6   11  2
6   7   18  4
7   8   42  3
8   3   36  3
9   5   5   12
10  4   7   6
11  4   12  22
12  4   3   44
13  4   26  1
14  12  37  3
15  5   12  1
16  6   18  11
17  3   12  32
18  3   3   47
19  15  24  4
20  18  37  3
21  14  40  4
22  16  33  1
23  10  35  1
24  12  47  3
25  11  42  2
26  5   3   14
27  5   42  1
28  5   19  1
29  2   3   5
30  2   12  1
31  6   40  1
32  6   30  3
33  6   24  3
34  4   13  1
35  14  24  2
36  18  26  1
37  13  39  2
38  16  40  2
39  10  42  1
40  4   6   18
41  4   20  1
42  2   16  3
43  6   42  2
44  6   20  2
45  14  30  2
46  11  45  3
47  5   22  1
48  6   23  1
```

The graph plots accurately items both its dimensions and its quantities
Print bin placement for each item ID on 5th column in the data

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to do the job of the algorithm, packing items into one bin at a time. Instead of that, throw in an estimated number of bins and let the library use the minimum needed bins to get the job done. I calculated the total area of all rectangles and added 50% for good measure as an estimated area needed in the bins, calculated the number of bins by dividing by the area of a single bin et voilà:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rectpack import newPacker

# Load data from the Excel file
file_path = "data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Detect column names
item_identity_column = df.columns[0]
width_column = df.columns[1]
height_column = df.columns[2]
amount_column = df.columns[3]

# Extract width, height, and amount from the DataFrame
rectangles = [(row[item_identity_column], row[width_column], row[height_column], row[amount_column]) for _, row in df.iterrows()]

# Initialize the packer
packer = newPacker()

# Set bin size
bin_width, bin_height = 81, 22


# Estimate number of bins needed assuming 50% extra area needed

n_bins = int(sum([width * height * amount for _, width, height, amount in rectangles]) * 1.5 / (bin_width * bin_height))

# Pack the rectangles into the bins

# Add a new bin (container)
for i in range(n_bins):
    packer.add_bin(bin_width, bin_height)

# Add rectangles to the packer
for (i, width, height, amount) in rectangles:
    for j in range(amount):
        packer.add_rect(width, height, rid=f'{i}_{j}')

# Pack the rectangles into the current bin
packer.pack()

for current_bin in range(len(packer.bin_list())):

    # Retrieve the packed rectangles for the current bin
    packed_rectangles = packer[current_bin]
        
    # Plot the rectangles and label their centers for the current bin
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7.5))
    for rect in packed_rectangles:
        x, y, w, h = rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x, y), w, h, linewidth=1, edgecolor='b', facecolor='none'))
        ax.text(x + w / 2, y + h / 2, f"#{rect.rid}", ha='center', va='center', color='r')
    
        # Add lines for distance (1 unit) between centers
        for other_rect in packed_rectangles:
            if rect != other_rect:
                other_x, other_y = other_rect.x + other_rect.width / 2, other_rect.y + other_rect.height / 2
                distance = ((x + w / 2 - other_x) ** 2 + (y + h / 2 - other_y) ** 2) ** 0.5
                if distance <= 1:
                    ax.plot([x + w / 2, other_x], [y + h / 2, other_y], color='gray', linestyle='--')
    
    # Add axis lines with a scale of 5 units
    ax.set_xticks(range(0, bin_width + 1, 5))
    ax.set_yticks(range(0, bin_height + 1, 5))
    ax.grid(True, linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
    
    # Set axis limits
    ax.set_xlim(0, bin_width)
    ax.set_ylim(0, bin_height)
    
    # Set aspect ratio to be equal
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    
    # Set axis labels
    ax.set_xlabel('Length')
    ax.set_ylabel('Width')
    
    # Set graph title
    ax.set_title(f'Placement #{current_bin + 1}')
    
    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
```